# Why duplication of products in prestashop backend

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have more than 1000 products in my store . How can i know the product is a duplicate or not.

when I try to delete one of my product , regardless of deleting the product, some other products are updated.
I found out (if a product have duplicates then ,when deleting any of the product , other duplicate products will be updated.).[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can run an SQL query to find the duplicates rows

```
SELECT reference, COUNT(*) n
FROM ps_product
GROUP BY reference
HAVING n > 1
ORDER BY n DESC
```